# Javascript array push issue or loop issue

Tags: javascript

When I'm running my code I'm going into 'do' loop, then I'm entering input 'new' and then trying to add new array, but for some reason my code starting looping in `if(answ == "new")`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var answ;
var arr = [];
do{
    answ = prompt("What would like to do?");
if(answ == "new"){
    var add = prompt("Add new todo: ");
    add = arr.push(answ);
}

else if(answ == "list"){
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i){
      answ = answ + arr[i] + '<br>';
  }

}

else if(answ == "delete"){
    var choose = prompt("Which one (index)?");
    delete arr[choose];
}
}while(answ !== "quit")
```

**Don't run in browser in current form** (never ending loop)

Comment: you're asking "What would like to do:" both initially in your loop and again if it doesn't match anything; this means you're going to have to "quit" twice. Just get rid of the second one and you should be fine.

Comment: The `else` at the end is useless! Just get rid of it!

Comment: @Hamms I tried it, but it still looping in
'if (answ == "new") {
    var add = prompt("Add new todo: ");
    add = arr.push(answ);
  }'

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "looping in 'if (answ == "new")'"?

Comment: @Hamms So when I run the program it's asking me "What would like to do?" then I answer 'new'. After that its asking me "Add new todo: ". And it should take one input and then ask again "What I would like to do", but instead its asking to add new todo.

Comment: That's not the behavior I get; once I add a new todo, it then prompts me for what I would like to do as it should. Are you getting any errors in the developer console when you run this?

Comment: You're not closing the last bracket in your if  statement.  If you update your code, please re-post.

Comment: After closing the bracket, do you still get the same problem?

Comment: put the command `debugger;` and open your DevTools before running, to debug

Comment: @Ibu Yes I still getting dame issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you Mark.

there were some errors with you logic and storing values and also you were not showing the values, if what I suggest is right.

```js
var answ;
var arr = [];
do {
  answ = prompt("What would like to do?");
  if (answ == "new") {
    var add = prompt("Add new todo: ");
    arr.push(add);
  } else if (answ == "list") {
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      output += arr[i] + '\r\n';
    }
    alert('listing:' + '\r\n' + output );

  } else if (answ == "delete") {
    var choose = prompt("Which one (index)?");
    arr.splice(choose,1);
  } else {
    if(answ !== "quit")
      alert('option invalid!');
  }
} while (answ !== "quit")
```

Comment: I see what you did and it looks better, but I'm still getting loop with "Add new todo: " message.

Comment: what do you want to do? once you type new... you wanna keep adding todo's?

Comment: No, I want program to ask "What would like to do?" and then you'll answer what you'll need until you'll quit it.

Comment: testing this code you only get loop on what would you like to do, if you type something different of  new .. list .. delete .. or quit

Comment: I added "option ivalid" if you type something different than the options... see if it's what you were looking for

Comment: I tried it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and it worked but on my [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) it still stuck in a loop.

Comment: Probably it's not being refreshed though